# Well-Ordering Proof in Cunningham

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, order-theory, well-orders

In Cunningham's Proof [1] of the Well-Ordering Principle (assuming $\textsf{AC}$), he begins by considering the set $\mathcal{W} = \{ \preceq | \preceq \text{a well-ordering on a subset of } A  \}$ for some arbitrary set $A$. He then defines the "continuation" relation $\unlhd$ on $\mathcal{W}$ as follows:

$$
\text{For any } \preceq, \preceq^{'} \in \mathcal{W}, \\
\preceq \: \unlhd \: \preceq^{'} \Longleftrightarrow \text{(i)} \preceq \: \subseteq \: \preceq^{'} \text{and (ii) if } x \preceq^{'} y \text{ and } y \preceq y, \text{then } x \preceq y
$$

where "$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary." Firstly, considering the fact that $\preceq \:$ is, by definition, a well-ordering on some subset of $A$, why is the reflexivity requirement ($y \preceq y$) needed? It was my understanding that this was already satisfied by virtue of well-orders being total orders (which, I think, require reflexivity).

More broadly, why is (ii) needed at all? I'm having a hard time finding an example of a superset to some relation $\preceq \: \in \mathcal{W}$ that doesn't satisfy this property. Could any of you offer a simple example of a superset that does not satisfy (ii)?

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

[1] $\textit{Set Theory: A First Course}$ by Daniel Cunningham (2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So elements of $W$ are well-orderings on subsets of $A$. To make this clearer, we can write $(B,\preceq)\in W,$ where $B\subset A$ and $\preceq$ is a well-ordering on $B$. We can rewrite the two conditions as $(B,\preceq)\trianglelefteq(B',\preceq')$ if

1. $B\subset B'$ and for any $a,b\in B,$ we have $a\preceq b\Longrightarrow a\preceq'b.$
2. If $a\preceq'b$ (which implies that $a,b\in B'$) and $b\in B,$ then $a\in B$ and $a\preceq b$.

As Andreas said, writing $y\preceq y$ implies that $y\in B$ (because this is the set on which $\preceq$ is defined). Since $\preceq$ is a well-order and thus reflexive, we have $y\preceq y\Longleftrightarrow y\in B.$

Let's do an example. Let $A=\{a,b\}$. Then there are five well-ordered subsets of $A$: $$\emptyset,\quad\{a\},\quad\{b\},\quad\{a<b\},\quad \{b<a\}.$$
Now you can check that $\{a\}\trianglelefteq\{a<b\}$. However $\{a\}\not\trianglelefteq\{b< a\}.$ The well-ordered set $\{b<a\}$ clearly extends the singleton $\{a\}$, so they satisfy (1). But it doesn't satisfy (2), because $b<a$ but $b\notin \{a\}$ (in the language of condition 2, this is $b\preceq' a$ and $a\in B$, but $b\notin B$).

If $B'$ is any well-ordered set and $B\subset B'$ is a well-ordered subset satisfying the above two conditions, we often say that $B$ is an initial segment of $B'$. Check that this is equivalent to the following: $$\text{Either }B=B'\text{ or there is some }b\in B'\text{ with }B=\{a\in B':a<b\}.$$
This is important in the proof of the well-ordering theorem. Suppose that $\mathscr C\subset W$ is a totally-ordered subset under $\trianglelefteq$. Condition (1) ensures that $\bigcup_{B\in\mathscr C}\!B$ has a total ordering extending that of any $B\in \mathscr C$. But the union might not be well-ordered. For example, every set $\{1/n,\dots,1/3,1/2,1\}$ is well-ordered, but the union $\{1/n:n\text{ a positive integer}\}$ is not well-ordered. Condition (2) is designed to ensure that the union is well-ordered.

In general, the concept of "initial segment" makes the ordinal numbers well-ordered (modulo some detail about proper classes). Specifically, if $A,B$ are well-ordered sets, we have one of the following:

3. There is a unique order-preserving injection $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $f(A)\trianglelefteq B.$
4. There is a unique order-preserving injection $f:B\rightarrow A$ such that $f(B)\trianglelefteq A.$

If both (3) and (4) are true, then there is a unique order-preserving bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion: could you clarify exactly how/why $\{ 1 <  0 \}$ is a well-ordering? The other cases are clear ($\emptyset$ is vacuously well-ordered, the singletons are trivially well-ordered, and $0<1$ is well-ordered in the standard way).

Comment: Ah! I see how my use of numerals was confusing. I changed $0$ and $1$ to $a$ and $b$, which will hopefully clarify the example. We are considering any well-ordering on a subset, so we can define either ordering on $\{a,b\}$. The two possibilities are just given by choosing which element is greater and which is lesser.

Comment: The change to $a$ and $b$ is much easier to understand – thanks. Would you mind demonstrating how the second condition is met in $ \{ a \} \unlhd \{ a < b \}$? If you represent the first well ordering as $\preceq_{1} = \{ (a, a) \}$ and the second as $\preceq_{2} = \{ (a, a), (b, b), (a, b) \}$ (as $a \preceq b$), it is clear that $\preceq_{1} \subseteq \preceq_{2}$, but it's unclear to me how the second condition holds. This question has been stumping me for some time...

Comment: Sure, you can either use the equivalent condition that I defined or you can go directly from condition (2). There's not much to check here, because the only pair satisfying the conditions of (2) is just (a,a). For an example with a nontrivial pair, you can try showing that $\{a<b\}\trianglelefteq \{a<b<c\}.$

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to reflexivity, $y\preceq y$ is just saying that $y$ is in the subset of $A$ that $\preceq$ well-orders.